# How can I model a non-symmetrical animal?

Tags: topology, mirror

In short, I am trying to achieve a lowpoly model of an animal looking to one side. I have up until now been using the mirror modifier for my models but now I want to add a bit more character by having it looking to one side. I of course then want to mirror the head, just facing a direction.

I have drawn the model already and my plan was to just manipulate the head to suit.

QUESTION: How can I achieve this and mirror the head?

Am I going about this the right way?

I can share pictures later if this will help.

Regards, Jack

Comment: Eventually you have to apply the mirror modifier (save a copy of the character before you do) and then make the modifications if you want the model to be asymmetric. But it sounds like you want to pose your model, which is done by adding an armature (skeleton) and manipulating the armature.

Comment: a solution would be to create a symmetrical object, then parent it to an armature, and move the head bone. This way you always keep the default pose. You could also use the Proportional Editing option to move or rotate the head, or the Pose brush, in Sculpt mode, but these 2 solutions are destructive

Comment: Great. And thanks a bunch for your comments. I have managed to have a play around with the Armature feature, my follow up question would be why does it snap back to symmetrical when I go back to edit mode? The piece if for a sheet metal sculpture and I need to flatten faces once it's posing. Thanks again.

Comment: UPDATE: I have managed to select then right click and 'convert to' mesh. Now it appears that I can edit it in 'edit mode'